# Apache POI org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI and I'm facing an issue when evaluating a formula cell.

This is my code:

```
XSSFCell cellvalue = sheet.getRow(6).getCell(2);
if (cellvalue.getCellType() == cellvalue.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
   evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cellvalue);
}
```

The formula:

```
=C6/Num_Input and Num_Input = F36
```

The issue:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException:
Cell reference expected after sheet name at index 18.
```

Comment: What is the text of the formula?

Comment: =C6/Num_Input

and Num_Input = F36,   thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, leave POI and check in excel itself if the formula is working fine. There is no problem at POI end. I wrote this sample code and it's working fine.

```
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(workbook);
        XSSFCell cellvalue = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        sheet.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue(2);
        sheet.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue(5);
        cellvalue.setCellFormula("B1+C1");
        if (cellvalue.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
           evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cellvalue);
        }
        System.out.println(cellvalue.getNumericCellValue());
```

It evaluates to 2 + 5 = 7 as it should.